# Could Q make Data human?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data, star-trek-q

I remember an episode of The Next Generation where at the end Q gave Data a gift, which was experiencing laughter. But before Q gave the laughter to him, Data thought Q wanted to make him human. Is it possible Q really could have made Data human?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102325/are-the-people-created-by-q-actually-real-people-or-are-they-just-illusions-and/102327#102327

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why not. They can turn Humans into Qs, and Qs into humans.

They also turn Q back into a Q after he's been human in Q2.

Comment: Apples and oranges. Data may not technically be alive.

Comment: How would data handle the transition

Comment: @Axelrod the Q are not life as we know it.

Comment: @Axelrod Irrelevant. Q can apparently make life out of *nothing*. There is no established reason he couldn't make a human out of Data. Whether the result would still *be* Data in a meaningful way is one for the philosophers.

Comment: That's my point he's not a biological being

Comment: @Darren is Q now or has he gone beyond that?

Comment: Am saying data is not a biological being I don't think he could make him human, and all the people Q has created are more like simulations

Comment: @Darren [Not necessarily](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102325/are-the-people-created-by-q-actually-real-people-or-are-they-just-illusions-and/102327#102327).

Comment: The people he creates for his jokes are  just the same as holodeck characters

Comment: Maybe. This is not canonically established.

Comment: @user40790 So Data can pick up Thor's hammer, and that does not mean "worthy"?

Answer (score 8):

**Probably Yes.**

In *Hide & Q* there is a moment on the bridge when Riker is about to make Data human. Although Data declines the offer, Riker appears to have no doubts that he is capable of making the change.

> RIKER: Data.
>   DATA: No. No, sir.
>   RIKER: But it's what you've always wanted, Data, to become human.
>   DATA: Yes, sir, that is true. But I never wanted to compound one illusion with another. It might be real to Q, perhaps even you, sir. But it would not be so to me. Was it not one of the Captain's favourite authors who wrote, This above all, to thine own self be true? Sorry, Commander, I must decline.
>   <sub>http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/111.htm</sub>

Later, in *Déjà Q* Data warns off Q from making him human, to which Q responds that he'd never curse Data in that way. While Q would be unlikely to admit to not being able to change Data, we can probably assume that it would've been within his power.

> Q: Yes, once again I've overstayed my welcome. As a human, I was ill-equipped to thank you, but as myself you have my everlasting gratitude. Until next time. Ah, but before I go, there's a debt I wish to repay to my professor of the humanities. Data, I've decided to give you something very, very special.
>   DATA: If your intention is to make me human, Q.
>   Q: No, no, no, no, no, no. I would never curse you by making you human. Think of it as a going away present.
>   <sub>http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/161.htm</sub>

Comment: I'd go so far as to say "absolutely yes", citing the fact that Q is essentially omnipotent.

Comment: @Richard I'm leaving open the possibility that he couldn't. There are some things that we've seen Qs cannot do (such as killing them-self), and as [Darren](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/could-q-make-data-human/115760#comment281526_115759) mentioned, all of the people Q has created were more like simulations than actual beings.

Comment: The Q seem to be perfectly capable of suicide. What they can't do is overrule 2 Q, though presumably 3 Q could.

Comment: We really don't know if the people Q created were real or simulations. We just don't have enough info for that. However since the Q span the continuum it really isn't beyond belief.

Comment: A lot of people here are lowballing Q. There is nothing anywhere to suggest that Q couldn't easily turn Data into a human, or a dog, or a microbe, or anything else.

Comment: Well, there is a little trick here -- would it still be Data after such a change? It seems like such a change would be trivial to Q: positronic brain to biological brain but there is a change in substance. Human brains run slower than computers. (If Q turns you into a dog do you lose the ability to comprehend at a human level?). Seems not so clear-cut.